# Object Required Error on VBA (submitting IE form using VBA)

Tags: vba, runtime-error

My code was working perfectly fine a few hours ago. But when I open the document now and run it, I get the error:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

Here's my code:

```
 Dim ieApp As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 ieApp.Visible = True
 ieApp.Navigate = "<url here; sorry, its confidential>"

 Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
 Loop

 Dim ieElement As Object
 Set ieElement = ieApp.Document.getElementById("i_specialist")
 ieElement.Value = "TestValue"
```

The error points to:

> Set ieElement = ieApp.Document.getElementById("i_specialist")

I really have no idea what went wrong. I'm thinking two possible causes:
- Object type is wrong
- Something went wrong with loading the page that the code can't find the field

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you checked in the html document page that an html element with the id i_specialist is exist?
anyway when im working with htmlElements im doing it like this.. worth to give it a try...

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .document.all.Item("i_specialist").Value = "TestValue"


    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative code! Replaced mine with this and it worked :) Still not sure though where it went wrong.. i_specialist exists in the HTML.